# InitelliJ Idea, ReactApp and Flow: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, flow-js

Flow displays errors, where there are none. Eg:

[image: errors]

Restart with `flow stop` and `flow` wont help it.

If I close the file and reopen it, the errors disappear, but other errors appear as I continue coding.

My flow version:

```
"flow-bin": "^0.125.1"
```

Any ideas how I can get rid of these annoying errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be an issue with Flow LSP. Try unchecking `javascript.flow.use.lsp` in **Registry** (in **Help | Find Action**, type `Registry...` to locate it)